# Install two versions of Xcode?

Tags: xcode

Can I install two versions of Xcode on my Mac? I'm planning to install 10.5 and 10.6. If this is possible please let me know...

Kevin

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, what?  The version of xcode on snowy builds 10.5 and 10.6 apps.  If you partition your hard drive and have 10.5 and .6 on each separate partition then you need xcode on each one to work

Answer (score 1):

If you have OS X 10.6, you should be able to target 10.5 (as well as 10.6, of course) from within that version. You should not have two separate installs of Xcode.

Maybe do some Googling to find out more details on how to do it. [Here's](http://www.meandmark.com/blog/files/supporting-older-versions-of-macosx.html) something to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already pointed out, installing two version of Xcode is probably not necessary.  However, to answer the question directly, it is possible to do so.  At install time, you will need to specify a directory different than the default.  For instance, instead of /Developer/... put the second install in /DeveloperXcode3.1/... or something like that.

That said, the only time I've found a need to do that is with beta versions.